# MPMoviePlayer or AVPlayer play advertisements(ads) in the middle of a video iOS

Tags: ios7, youtube-api, xcode6, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

We are trying to play `ads` while playing a video using `MPMoviePlayer` or `AVPlayer` in our `iOS` app. What is the best way to achieve this functionality? Can anyone suggest the right way to make it work as `YOUTUBE Player` which plays `ads` in the middle of video.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/androidios/AVEditDemo is the wonderful example for merging multiple videos in iOS. 
Here is apple `WWDC` video for editing videos in iOS http://adcdownload.apple.com//videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_407__editing_media_with_av_foundation.mov